# Clearing cache is not working in symfony 2.8

Tags: php, bash, symfony, zsh, symfony-2.8

I'm making a website on Symfony 2.8 and when I try to run `php app/console cache:clear` it gives me below error:

#### in zsh:

> zsh: segmentation fault  php app/console cache:clear

#### in bash:

> Segmentation fault: 11

I can't clear my cache because of this. How to fix it?

Comment: Check out this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3276396/1173474)

Comment: Here's an alternative : `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Comment: @EmanuelOster thanks for the answer. But i think it's not the right solution, sorry. Because `php app/console cache:clear` works fine on my another symfony project. So i guess there is a problem in my symfony project. But don't know where it is.

Comment: @DOZ yeah i know it. But i want to use command line option.

Comment: If another app on the same machine (same version and same user) works then troubleshoot but opening up app/AppKernel and start commenting out your bundles.

Comment: @Cerad i'll try it :)